Why does a function call resolve to a using declaration over a using directive in C++?
I am a little confused what's the exact reason the following code compiles (and is not ill-formed):
namespace A
{
    void f() { }
}

namespace B
{
    void f() {}
}

int main()
{
    using  A::f;
    using namespace B;
    f();
    
}

We distinguish between a using directive and a using declaration. The latter, being a declaration, adds declarations to the declarative region of the program, whereas the former merely makes certain names usable within that region. Clearly, the using directive has much less power in this regard. Thus, when we call f(), since we have already declared the name f in the declarative region with the using declaration, during the qualified name lookup (ns_name::something, ::something), names in B will not be checked at all.
But then I remembered for f() the compiler will use unqualified lookup.

See this answer that explains this in detail. Note the second example in particular.

tldr of the dupe: Basically Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears but a using-declaration does. And so when lookup happens, the one introduced by the using declaration is found first and search stops and so this is used.

It's because you put them into main: the name introduced by the using-declaration at the block scope hides names from enclosing scopes. using-declaration adds the name to the current scope; using-directive "merges" names from the nominated namespace into the enclosing namespace, but not the current scope. If you put the two at file scope, you'll get the error you expected
